# Scrapy - try all IDs inside a directory without recursive link searching

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Assume we want to crawl a specific directory from a website where page names are integer IDs in a specific range, for example `/book/BOOK_ID` where BOOK_ID is from 0 to 2,000,000, I don't want to crawl the whole website, and there is no single page containing all the links. Using search pages are not allowed (for empty search) or is inefficient. So we just want to iterate over all those IDs in that range, and try downloading pages, and simply ignore 404 error.

But since Scrapy is pretty powerful and huge and handles a lot of other things, I want to know if it's possible with Scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) to start requests for `/book/BOOK_ID` pages:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for book_id in xrange(1, 20000000):
        yield Request('https://my_site.com/book/{book_id}'.format(book_id=book_id),
                      callback=self.parse_book)

def parse_book(self, response):
    # parse the response
```

Also, Scrapy would, by default, ignore `404`. But, if you need, you can handle it, see:

- [HttpErrorMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware)